# General form of a series

Tags: sequences-and-series, generating-functions, time-series

I arrived at this series while solving some problem:

```
{-1, 14, -90, 350, -910, 1638, -2002, 1430, 0, -1430, 2002, -1638, 910, -350, 90, -14, 1}
```

Could anyone help me in knowing the general form/term of the n-th element in this series?

Or you could help me learn how to find the general term myself. I don't know where to start.

Thanks.

Comment: A finite number of terms does not identify a sequence. How did you come up with this?

Comment: @KarolisJuodelė I'm doing a complicated quantum simulation, and I'm trying to extract some kind of a general, approximate law after simplifying a very complicated Hamiltonian. Those numbers represent the coefficients of the wave modulation (sin(...)) I have in the wave function's expectation value. I need to reconstruct them to build the general law.

Comment: [oeis](http://oeis.org/search?q=1%2C+14%2C+90%2C+350%2C+910%2C+1638&language=english&go=Search) is your friend.

Comment: @Goos it couldn't find the second series... unfortunately.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Starting with index $0$ this is
$${(-1)}^{1+n}\left(\binom{14}{n}-\binom{14}{n-2}\right)$$
(using the fact that $\binom{N}m=0$ if $m<0$ or $m>N$.

Comment: Thanks man! That's genius. But how did you come up with this? I have a couple of other series I need to figure out. Is it simply trial and error?

Comment: The $(-1)^{n+1}$ was obvious. Then I have only remark that it starts almost like $\binom{14}{n}$. I have computed the difference and remarked that I got the same numbers, only shifted.

Comment: Could you help me with one more series?

Comment: @TheQuantumPhysicist. You should ask a new question on math.SE. Someone may find the answer. This might be anyone, including me :)

Comment: I just hope it's not illegal to open multiple questions with the same topic :)

Comment: @TheQuantumPhysicist. Well you should flood the site with very similar questions, for sure. Edit your question if you feel better this way.

Comment: OK, I added more! Thanks for the suggestion.

Comment: Finally asked [here](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/667175)