# General form of a series (another one).

Tags: sequences-and-series

I arrived at this series while solving some problem:

$$\{1, -10, 42, -90, 78, 78, -286, 286, 0, -286, 286, -78, -78, 90, -42, 10, -1\}$$

Could anyone help me in knowing the general form/term of the $n$th element in this series?

Or you could help me learn how to find the general term myself? I don't know where to start.

Thanks.

Comment: Make things a little simpler by dividing each term by 7.

Comment: @GerryMyerson Thanks for the hint!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This one is more difficult than the [preceding](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/667144/general-form-of-a-series/667152)...

I found the result
$$(-1)^n\left(\binom{10}{n}-3\binom{10}{n-2}+3\binom{10}{n-4}-\binom{10}{n-6}\right).$$

I've got it using the same trick. Only the factor 3 was more tricky.

Comment: This is lovely! Thank you!